# SMTP Repeater loger

Tags: c#, vb.net, smtp

I'm trying to do a repeater (as a proxy) for logging the data exchange between a SMTP client and a server. I thought it was only easy as:
Listening the client;

- Listening client IP connection;
- On call, connect to the server;
- Send back server message;
- Send the client messages to the server and return the server feedback to the client;

But, as I saw, some servers as MS exchange send multiple feedback witch are breaking the handshaking.Like:

- 250-SIZE 41943040
- 250-PIPELINING
- 250-DSN
- 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
- 250-STARTTLS
- 250-AUTH LOGIN
- 250-8BITMIME
- 250-BINARYMIME
- 250 CHUNKING

  Here is the class

  Imports System.Text
  Imports System.Net
  Imports System.Net.Sockets
  Imports System.Threading

  Public Class SmtpProxy

  ```
  Private client As TcpClient
  Private cltstream As NetworkStream
  Private cltreader As System.IO.StreamReader
  Private cltwriter As System.IO.StreamWriter

  Private smtpserver As New TcpClient
  Private srvstream As NetworkStream
  Private srvreader As System.IO.StreamReader
  Private srvwriter As System.IO.StreamWriter


  Private Shared mHostSrv As String
  Public Shared Property HostSrv() As String
      Get
          Return mHostSrv
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As String)
          mHostSrv = value
      End Set
  End Property

  Private Shared mServerPort As Integer = 25
  Public Shared Property ServerPort() As Integer
      Get
          Return mServerPort
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As Integer
      )
          mServerPort = value
      End Set
  End Property

  Private Shared mUserNm As String
  Public Shared Property UserNm() As String
      Get
          Return mUserNm
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As String)
          mUserNm = value
      End Set
  End Property

  Private Shared mPassword As String
  Public Shared Property Password() As String
      Get
          Return mPassword
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As String)
          mPassword = value
      End Set
  End Property


  Public Sub New(ByVal client As TcpClient)
      Me.client = client
      cltstream = client.GetStream()
      cltreader = New System.IO.StreamReader(cltstream)
      cltwriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(cltstream)
      cltwriter.NewLine = vbCr & vbLf
      cltwriter.AutoFlush = True

  End Sub


  Public Shared Sub Start() 'ByVal args As String())
      Dim listener As New TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 2525)
      listener.Start()
      While True
          Dim handler As New SmtpProxy(listener.AcceptTcpClient())
          Dim thread As Thread = New System.Threading.Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf handler.Run))
          thread.Start()
      End While
  End Sub


  Public Sub Run()

      If mHostSrv Like "*.*.*.*" Then
          Dim IpS As IPAddress = Nothing
          IpS = IPAddress.Parse(mHostSrv)
          smtpserver.Connect(IpS, mServerPort)
      Else
          smtpserver.Connect(mHostSrv, mServerPort)
      End If

      srvstream = smtpserver.GetStream
      srvreader = New System.IO.StreamReader(srvstream)
      srvwriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(srvstream)
      srvwriter.NewLine = vbCrLf
      srvwriter.AutoFlush = True


      Dim srvline As String = srvreader.ReadLine
      cltwriter.WriteLine(srvline)
      Debug.Print("Server sent: {0}", srvline & vbCrLf)

      Try

          Dim line As String = cltreader.ReadLine
          While line IsNot Nothing
              Debug.Print("Read line {0}", line)
              srvwriter.WriteLine(line)
              Application.DoEvents()
              srvline = srvreader.ReadLine()
              Debug.Print("Server sent: {0}", srvline)
              cltwriter.WriteLine(srvline.Replace("-", " "))
              Application.DoEvents()
              line = cltreader.ReadLine()
          End While
      Catch ex As Exception
          client.Close()
          smtpserver.Close()
      End Try

  End Sub
  ```

  End Class

I tried to read multiple server lines at a time but in the meantime the client return and error if I send the whole returned server lines...

```
Private Function ReadSrvLines() As String

    Dim strRet As String = ""
    Do
        If strRet Like "220*" OrElse srvreader.EndOfStream Then Exit Do
        Dim strTmp As String = srvreader.ReadLine
        If strTmp Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        strRet &= strTmp.Replace("-", " ") & vbCrLf
        cltwriter.WriteLine(strTmp.Replace("-", " "))
        Debug.Print("Server sent: {0}", strTmp.Replace("-", " ") & vbCrLf)
    Loop

    Return strRet
End Function
```

Then is anyone have any solutions to propose?

Thanks all!!

Frank

Comment: I tried to change my approach according to the Ashigore comment and combining the server return message with minus in a whole string, but the smtp client seems not understanding it, it stuck after the last message returned like:

Comment: Server sent: 220 mail.xxx.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 1 Oct 2013 11:31:30 -0400
Client sent: EHLO PC1112

Server sent: 250-mail.xxx.com Hello [192.168.6.44]
Server sent: 250-SIZE 41943040
Server sent: 250-PIPELINING
Server sent: 250-DSN
Server sent: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Server sent: 250-STARTTLS
Server sent: 250-AUTH LOGIN
Server sent: 250-8BITMIME
Server sent: 250-BINARYMIME
Server sent: 250 CHUNKING

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform simultaneous asynchronous reading/writing between client and server to make this work properly. SMTP responses can contain any number of lines and client or server can return a message without the need for a command (to say bye for example). Parsing the data is also unnecessary to achieve a basic log.

Edit: If it helps, if the 3 digit message number if followed by a (minus) rather than a (space) it means that there is another line to follow.

Comment: Haaa! That's why the minus, thanks a lot for the information!